# I'm having problems getting "All" of the "named" objects in the POST after a form submit

Tags: php, post

I have a form detail.php that utilizes the POST method and processes data on action on process.php page

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">
```

I have a number of objects on my form (select, textarea, labels) some I get data for in the `$_POST` other's I do not.

For example one of my selects on my detail.php page

```
<select name="ddstatusid">
```

when echoed on process.php

```
echo $_POST['ddstatusid'];
```

I get $_POST data as expected. If using the following label on the same form **custno**

```
<td width="107" class="pl-sm-5" name="custno"><?php echo $data['CUST_NO'];?></td>
```

and echoing it on process.php

```
echo $_POST['custno'];
```

I get an error:

> "SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for 
>   ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: custno in... "

What am I missing here, it seems like it should be so obvious but I'm not seeing it..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is the input field for `custno`? Simply setting the `name` attribute on a random HTML element does not mark it to be submitted with the form

Comment: Add your html for too

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <td width="107" class="pl-sm-5" name="custno">
> ```

The data submitted by a form will include only that expressed by successful form controls.

A table data cell is not a form control.

Only `input`, `textarea`, `select` and `button` elements can be.

If you want to submit the contents of a `td` element, then put an `input` inside it (and give the `name` to the `input`). This could be a *hidden* input.

Comment: Also, you could include the unchecked checkboxes too, as they are not sent either :)

Comment: @MateiMihai — There are *lots* of reasons why a form control might not be successful, being an unchecked checkbox is only one of them. I'm not going to provide a comprehensive list here as it isn't relevant to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

A td is not a form element that will be submitted as form data to the server. 
Maybe you confused sth or wanted to use

```
<input type="hidden" name="custno" value="<?php echo $data['CUST_NO'];?>" />
```

Please notice that this might not save against XSS-attacks.*

* = Is $data['CUST_NO'] always in valid state?

Comment: "Please notice that this is not save against CRSF-attacks" — While the code is vulnerable to CSRF, I think you mean XSS.

Comment: Thank you for the reply's. I'm not sure what "Put on hold" means from the moderator since there was an error being generated and included in the question... I believe that you have answered my question though in that a form cell "name" is not submitted with the $_POST. 

What is the standard for submitting this data given my example as a cell, is it to create a hidden object and submit it that way as is suggested or is there a better way to approach this? I made the assumption that an object on the form was submitted by default and not only specific items